# How to associate file types with Code::blocks when the association dialog doesn't come?

Tags: c++, c, windows, windows-7, codeblocks

When I install codeblocks, there was an option about set this program for all c/c++ files and after that all file with .cpp, .C, .cxx, .cc extensions was associated to open with codeblocks as its default program. But, then I reinstall codeblocks then that options didnt come and I need to associate all cplusplus/c files to open with codeblocks as its default program. But why do I need this?

Operating system: windows 7 32 bit

I the 32 bit version of codeblocks with mingw compiler and the the version was 20.3. But why is tjis happening? And if it's not the right place to ask this question then plz tell me where to ask?

Comment: Probably during installation it overwritten settings files. If it come back to default values that can be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Code::Blocks go to `Settings` / `Environment...` / `General Settings` and to the right of `Check & set file associations (Windows Only)` click on `Set now`

Comment: Did it solve your problem? Please don't forget to accept the answer if it did.